# Angular 7 Reactive forms - link form group in FormArray to object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a formarray of formgroups

```
const skillsControl = <FormArray>this.form.controls['skills'];

this.selectedCourse.requiredSkills.forEach(skill => {
    const s = this.fb.group({
                instructor: ['', Validators.required],
                ...other controls...
              });
    skillsControl.push(s);
}
```

Each selectedCourse will have a unique set of skills.

I need to be able to display the name of the skill, and then the form controls associated to that skill.

How do i associate the required skill object with its respective form group?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your form in this way:

```
  const items = new FormArray(this.skills.map(item => new FormGroup({
                name: new FormControl(item.name),
                instructor: new FormControl(item.instructor)
  })));

  this.myForm = new FormGroup({items: items});
```

I did a full example in stackblitz:

[Form Array exmple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnw4aj?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Not exactly what i was after, but it's helped me get to where i want to be. Thanks for this.